# Позиционирование иконки-шрифта в псевдоэлементе after

Tags: css, позиционирование, fontawesome

Не получается отцентрировать по вертикали иконку `fontawesome` в псевдоэлементе `:after`

Пробовал так же обычные картинки вместо иконок.

Стрелочка должна быть по центру с текстом

[image: Иконка снизу, а должна быть по центру]

```css
/* Container*/

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Header */

header {
  padding-top: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}


/* Nav */

.nav__link {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 55px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.nav__link:after {
  font: normal normal normal 10px/1 FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0dd";
  margin-left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="nav">
      <a class="nav__link" href="">Commercial</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавил 'position: relative;' ссылке, и абсолютное позиционирование элементу after

```
.nav__link{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 55px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.nav__link:after{
    font: normal normal normal 10px/1 FontAwesome;
    content: "\f0dd";
    position: absolute; top: 50%; right: -15px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```